# Angular: Storing data to be used on multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of names in a `.ts` file called `"domain-names.ts"`.

```js
import { Domain } from './library';

export const DOMAIN: Domain[] = [
  {id: 1, catergory: "testing" },
  {id: 2, catergory: "utilities" },
  {id: 3, catergory: "mocking" },
  {id: 4, catergory: "cryptograpghy" },
  {id: 5, catergory: "json" },
  {id: 6, catergory: "database" },
  {id: 7, catergory: "security" },
  {id: 8, catergory: "object-relational mapping" },
  {id: 9, catergory: "xml" }
];
```

I also have a `"this domain.service.ts"` file that fetches and saves across several classes.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Domain } from './library';
import { DOMAIN } from './domain-names';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class DomainService {

  constructor() { }

  getDomain(id: number): Observable<Domain>{
    return of(DOMAIN.find(domain => domain.id === id));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a checkbox form that compares two domain names. I want to save the domain names the user selects so that I can use the information to create graphs. I'm wondering how to save the domain names across multiple HTML pages based on what the user chooses using a checkbox style Form component.

I tried creating a component called compare to retrieve the domain names from the service and compare them, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-compare',
  templateUrl: './compare.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compare.component.css']
})
export class CompareComponent implements OnInit {

  domain: Domain;
  // private domainService: DomainService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute
  constructor() {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDomain();
  }

  getDomain(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.domainService.getDomain(id)
      .subscribe(domain => this.domain = domain);
  }

}
```

This is how I imagined the HTML code would look for the form:

```html
<form [formGroup]=”form” (submit)=”submit(form.value)”>
  <div *ngFor=”let  dom of domains.controls; let i=index”>
   <input type=”checkbox” [formControl]=”domain”/> {{domains.catergory}}
  </div>
  <button type=”submit”>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `observable` if you just want to get some data? Using an observable would make sense if some other component could change the domain, then `CompareComponent` would listen to those changes

Comment: @Pavlo I'm kinda new to angular and this is how I've been setting up my services based on a tutorial I looked at. I used it to simulate getting data from a server with the RxJS of() function

Comment: Just add them a couple variables to your service to store them. Services persist through route changes. so then you could just create a function called `getPreferences()` or something in your service which returns the stored values.

Comment: you can't embed TS in a snippet use stackblitz please